# How to shorten long names when performing folder to folder copy on server?

Tags: windows-server-2012, filesystems

I am preparing to move about 500 GB of user's data to a new directory structure on a Windows Server 2012. (255 limit)

Is there a way to automatically reduce the length of the filenames somehow during copy?

There is a *lot* of filenames that are too long, and doing this by hand could prove too long.

Comment: What do you want? reduce file size, or shorten names?

Comment: Shortening names would be fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a special filesystem, using robocopy should work just fine. Try robocopy with a subset of files to check if it works for you. Take a look at every switch robocopy has, you want to save logfiles for this process. the /tee switch is your friend. Suppress progress output in the logfiles and decide what you want to do with symbolic links. /XJ has worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Use `robocopy` for this. It's built-in in Windows Server 2012 and supports long pathnames > 256 characters.

Comment: But the filesystem may not.